# Vectorisation of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I'm working on numerical option pricing, and am now trying to implement vectorised inputs for performance reasons. The function I want to vectorise for `u`-inputs in the `GBM` class is as follows.

```
def spitzer_recurrence(self, m : int, u, x, t, T, K, num=False):
        p = np.zeros((m, m), dtype=complex)
        for I in range(m):
            p[0,I] = self.ana_a(I, u, t, (T-t)/m) / (I+1)
        
        out = p[0, m-1]
        
        for I in range(1, m):
            for J in range(m - I):
                for k in range(J+1):
                    p[I, J] += p[I-1, k] * p[0, J-k]
            out += p[I, m-1-I] / math.factorial(I+1)

        return out
```

where `ana_a()` is defined as

```
def ana_a(self, k, u, t, stepsize):
        tau_k = k * stepsize
        alpha = self.mu - self.sigma**2/2

        t1 = norm.cdf(-alpha*math.sqrt(tau_k)/(self.sigma))
        f1 = 0.5*np.exp(-0.5*u**2*self.sigma**2*tau_k + 1j*tau_k*u*alpha)
        f2 = erfc(-math.sqrt(tau_k/2) * (u*self.sigma*1j + alpha/self.sigma))
        return t1 + f1 * f2
```

Trying to input a np array into this fuction for `u` gives an error in the line `p[0,I] = self.ana_a(I, u, t, (T-t)/m) / (I+1)`, for trying to insert a np array into a matrix of scalars.

Is there a way to initialise p as a matrix of zero valued vectors?

***TEST PROGRAM***

```
xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
gbm = GBM(0.1, 0.2)
a1 = gbm.spitzer_recurrence(20, xs, 100, 0, 1, 100)
a2 = np.array([gbm.spitzer_recurrence(20, x, 100, 0, 1, 100) for x in xs])

print(a1 == a2)
```

running this script should result in an array of True, but does not.

Comment: You need to share `self.ana_a` to show why it cannot accept an array input.

Comment: Also, what is each input type? `u` is an array, `x`, `num`, and `K` are not used, and you don't give any indication of what `t` or `T` are, though I'd guess they are `float`s.

Comment: @jared, you are right, these are floats. i will add the definition of `ana_a`, but that is not where the problem lies.

Comment: What shape is `u`? Is it a matrix or a vector? Also, `i` is undefined in `ana_a`, so I cannot run your code. Assuming `u` is a vector, your first error with`p[0,I]` can probably be dealt with by doing `p[0] = ana_a(I,...)` where you define `I = np.arange(m)`. You will need to be careful of the shapes of things, but I cannot help with that without example inputs.

Comment: @jared, apologies. In the current code u is a scalar value, but i want to extend the code for u to be a vector of arbitrary length. Also, `i` is the imaginary unit, apologies for not speciying.

Comment: In an expression like ` p[0,I] = self.ana_a(I, u, t, (T-t)/m) / (I+1)`, if `ana_a` is returning an array, then `p` has to be initialized to an array such that `p[0,1]` is matching size array.  You just have to keep track of dimensions, both while writing code, and while testing.  Test pieces with small shapes.  Print shapes to verify your assumptions.  I have an interactive python session running where I can test pieces of code, and often copy code and results to my answers.

Comment: Please read this link on [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As is, we cannot run your code because of many missing variables. Try and bring this code into a new script and give us enough information to be able to run it. Some things that are still missing: `self.mu`, `self.sigma`, and an example input that produces the error. Also, if you're working with numpy arrays, use numpy functions, like `np.sqrt` instead of `math.sqrt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My own MRE

```py
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.special import erfc
import math
import numpy as np


def ana_a(k, u, t, stepsize):
    mu = 5.0
    sigma = 2.0
    tau_k = k * stepsize
    alpha = mu - sigma**2/2

    t1 = norm.cdf(-alpha*np.sqrt(tau_k)/sigma)
    f1 = 0.5*np.exp(-0.5*u**2*sigma**2*tau_k + 1j*tau_k*u*alpha)
    f2 = erfc(-np.sqrt(tau_k/2) * (u*sigma*1j + alpha/sigma))
    return t1 + f1 * f2

def spitzer_recurrence(m : int, u, x, t, T, K, num=False):
    p = np.zeros((m, m)+np.shape(u), dtype=complex)
    for I in range(m):
        p[0,I] = ana_a(I, u, t, (T-t)/m) / (I+1)
    
    out = p[0, m-1]
    
    for I in range(1, m):
        for J in range(m - I):
            for k in range(J+1):
                p[I, J] += p[I-1, k] * p[0, J-k]
        out += p[I, m-1-I] / math.factorial(I+1)

    return out

# Test that ana_a is vectorized
U=np.array([0,5,10])
r1 = np.array([ana_a(1,u,2.0, 0.01) for u in U])
r2 = ana_a(1,U,2.0,0.01)
if (r1==r2).all():
    print('ana_a is vectorized')
else:
    print('ana_a is NOT vectorized')


xs = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
a1 = spitzer_recurrence(20, xs, 100, 0, 1, 100)
a2 = np.array([spitzer_recurrence(20, x, 100, 0, 1, 100) for x in xs])
print('spitzed_recurrence vectorized', (a1==a2).all())
```

Note "R" stands for "reproducible" and that it is reproducible, because anyone can just copy it at home, and execute it, without having to figure out what those undefined symbols are.
So it includes the `import` part (some folks here are certainly good enough to solve your problem, while not aware that `norm.cdf` is probably `scipy.stats.norm.cdf`. After all, you can be very well accustomed to use numpy without doing any stats. Any way, even for me, who have already used those functions more than once, most of the time I spent to solve your problem was done in doing what needed so that `norm.cdf` and `erfc` works.

Likewise, you didn't provide the class. And you were right not to do so (that is the "M" of "MRE"). Class is not what cause problem, so no need to bother us with its definition. But then, what you provide should not rely on that missing class. So, no `GBM` in your test code, and no `self` anyway. And just hard code some values for `mu` and `sigma`. It is not as those value really matter; as long as they are as such as the function does return something usable to test it.

In fact, even my `MRE` is not minimal enough. `stepsize`, `t`, `m`, `x` (the one in the function, not the one you use for testing, which seems to be what is called `u` in the function), `t`, `K`, `num` could be all hard coded. Their value is not part of the problem. So all value but `u` aren't really necessary here.
Even further: since you trust that `ana_a` is vectorized (which it is only partly, since you use `math.sqrt` instead of `np.sqrt`. But as long as only `u` can be a vector, that is not a problem. I replaced them with `np.sqrt` tho)

So, since most of my time was spend into filling the holes here, I took the liberty to also use most of my answer ranting on MRE :)

## Vectorization of `spitzer_recurrence`

In first approach, the solution is simply to do exactly what you asked for: having `p` being a matrix of vectors instead of a matrix of scalar. And a matrix (2d array) of vectors (1d-array), is simply a 3d-arrary. So, it is just about replacing `p=np.zeros((m,m))` by `p=np.zeros((m,m,len(u))`

The only difficulty here is that we want the function to still work with scalars (most of the time, and probably in your case, we don't really need this. We know in advance what parameter is scalar what which are not. People who are writing general purpose library, such as numpy, want usage to be quite multiform. But your function seems specific enough to suspect that in reality it would not be a problem to decide once for all that parameter `u` is a vector. But well, since your own test assumes that it can be both...)

So for that, I need `p` to be 2d if `u` is a scalar, and 3d if `u` is a 1d-vector. Good news is that `np.shape` can compute the shape of both an array and a scalar (which is, from numpy vectorized perspective a 0d-array, so `shape=()`). So shape of `p` is simply `(m,m)+np.shape(u)`. If is a scalar that is `(m,m)+()` aka `(m,m)`. If `u` is a 1d-array of size n, that is `(m,m)+(n,)` aka `(m,m,n)`.

## More vectorization

This is vectorized, that is, it does accept a vector as input. But there are still for loops in it. To benefits numpy's vectorization power, the ideal would be to remove all for loops from the code.

Note that even if you have a triple loop, there is not much to gain (not much more: we already spared a times ×200 factor with the simple previous vectorization (which was just about having p being 3D). Because when an algorithm consist essentially in a nested loop, the important loops to vectorized are the inner one. If your have 3 nested, 1000 iteration for loops, the inner one means to have some python calls 1000×1000×1000, the middle one 1000×1000, and the first one 1000. So, usually there is not so much to gain once the 1 or 2 most inner loops have been removed (depending on how negligible is the actual computation time compared to the overhead of the for loop itself, and of the python cost to call a function)

In your case, you have 2 loops for the 1st part of the computation (the one calling `ana_a`: one explicit, and one implicit, done inside `ana_a` by the vectorization we've done before).

Then 4 nested loops in the second part of the computation; 3 explicit, and 1 implicit, because of the vectorization on the 3rd axis of the `p[I-1, k] * p[0, J-k]` computation.

So in both case, the most inner loop is already vectorized (it is implicit; it is done inside numpy code, that computes the same thing for all values in the 3rd axis, that is for all `u`).

Nevertheless, we remove 1 more loop from each of those computations.

```
def spitzer2(m, u, x, t, T, K, num=False):
    p = np.zeros((m, m)+np.shape(u), dtype=complex)
    II = np.arange(m)[:,None]
    p[0,...] = (ana_a(II, u, t, (T-t)/m) / (II+1)).squeeze()
    
    out = p[0, m-1]
    
    for I in range(1, m):
        for J in range(m - I):
            p[I,J] = (p[I-1,:J+1] * p[0,J::-1]).sum(axis=0)
        out += p[I, m-1-I] / math.factorial(I+1)

    return out
```

Testing with

```
a3 = spitzer2(20, xs, 100, 0, 1, 100)
a4 = np.array([spitzer2(20, x, 100, 0, 1, 100) for x in xs])
print('same with scalar', np.allclose(a1,a3))
print('same with vector', np.allclose(a2,a4))
```

The trick here, for the 1st computation, is to have `ana_a` be able to vectorize for two parameters. `k` and `u`. Hence the importance, after all, to change your `math.sqrt` to `np.sqrt`: it didn't really matter when only `u` was non scalar, but if `k`, therefore `tau_k` can also be a vector, that becomes more important.
But since we want a double loop, it cannot be just vectors (otherwise it would compute `ana_a` with first k and first u, then second k and second u, then third k and third u, ... or even don't compute anything if the size of U vector is not the same as the size of the vector of k). We need to have 2 axis, one for the values of u, and another for the values of k. Then numpy broadcasting will do the rest, and compute `ana_a` for all possible combination of a `k` and a `u`, and return a 2d array of the corresponding result.

This is what `np.arange(I)[:,None]` is for: it is a vector of all possible values for k, but with 2 axes.

The `.squeeze` is because, in the case we call `ana_a` with a scalar, we expect a 1D-array (to fit in `p[0]`), but the division by `(II+1)` creates a 2D-array anyway (even if only with 1 row). `.squeeze` removes axis with only 1 row.

For the second part, we can (at least easily; some people may find a way to do more) remove the innner `for k` loop. That is after all just the sum of a element-wise multiplication; at least it is, if you invert p on its 2nd axis first.

## Timings

On my (slow) PC

| Method | execution time |
| --- | --- |
| Non vectorized | 5.81 seconds |
| simple vectorization (3d p) | 29 ms |
| 2d ana + vectorization of for k loop | 20 ms |

So, obviously the 1st vectorization was the important one (×200 gain, aka -99.5% reduction). But the second one still worth it (still a ×1.5 gain, or a -30% reduction)